# Orderby not working with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

The `orderby` clause with the Microsoft Graph API doesn't appear to work.

I tried to use `orderby` with a SharePoint list and while no error is given the results are never in the correct order. To test this I used the provided Explorer page https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer# . Using their examples I tried the orderby clauses below. No error but the order doesn't change.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/d7689e2b-941a-4cd3-bb24-55cddee54294/items?$orderby=id%20desc
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/d7689e2b-941a-4cd3-bb24-55cddee54294/items?$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime%20desc

I would expect the last modified date/time could cause issues but the orderby on the id field should be easy. Either the entire orderby is ignored or the descending part isn't working. Can anyone confirm this and/or point me to where I can add this to a bug tracker? I didn't see a way to raise the issue on the documentation page https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/overview/query_parameters .

Comment: Reproduced the problem. It seems to be a bug.